# Records are doubled when adding referenced entities using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem, when i add a new entity of `SessionImages`, and then add another one (By uploading it), it gets doubled.
For example :

1. Adding an image :
   [image]
2. Adding another one afterwards  :
   [image]

Here's my controller code :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SessionImages(FormCollection collection)
{
    int SessionID = Convert.ToInt32(collection[0]);
    Sessions SessionModel = sessionsRepo.GetSessionById(SessionID);
    bool uploadSucceded = Utility.Utility.UploadImages(this, Request.Files, Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Photos/Sessions", SessionModel.Name)));
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Request.Files[i].ContentLength == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        SessionImages ImageModel = new SessionImages
        {
            Name = Request.Files[i].FileName,
            Path = Path.Combine("~/Photos/Sessions/", SessionModel.Name, "actual", Request.Files[i].FileName),
            Session = SessionModel,
            SessionID = SessionID
        };
        sessionImagesRepo.Add(SessionModel, ImageModel);
    }            
    return RedirectToAction("SessionImages",SessionModel.ID);
}
```

Here's the `sessionImagesRepo.Add` method :

```
public SessionImages Add(Sessions SessionModel, SessionImages ImageModel)
{
    try
    {
        context.Entry(ImageModel).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
        SessionModel.PhotosCount = SessionModel.Images.Count;
        context.Entry(SessionModel).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;                
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    return ImageModel;
}
```

Here's my entities :

```
namespace FP.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Sessions
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int PhotosCount { get; set; }
        public string CoverPhoto { get; set; }
        public List<SessionImages> Images { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace FP.Domain.Entities
{
    public class SessionImages
    {
        public int ImageID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public int SessionID { get; set; }
        public Sessions Session { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the configuration :

```
namespace FP.Domain.Configurations
{
    public class SessionsConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Sessions>
    {
        public SessionsConfig()
        {
            ToTable("Sessions");
            Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.PhotosCount).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.CoverPhoto).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.Date).HasColumnType("date");
        }
    }
}


namespace FP.Domain.Configurations
{
    public class SessionImagesConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<SessionImages>
    {
        public SessionImagesConfig()
        {
            ToTable("SessionImages");
            HasKey(e => e.ImageID);
            Property(p => p.Path).IsRequired();
            HasRequired(i => i.Session)
                .WithMany(s => s.Images)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.SessionID);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the repository method like this:

```
public SessionImages Add(Sessions SessionModel, SessionImages ImageModel)
{
    try
    {
        SessionModel.Images.Add(ImageModel);
        SessionModel.PhotosCount = SessionModel.Images.Count;
        context.Entry(SessionModel).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;                
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    return ImageModel;
}
```

And in the action remove the line that I've commented:

```
    SessionImages ImageModel = new SessionImages
    {
        Name = Request.Files[i].FileName,
        Path = Path.Combine("~/Photos/Sessions/", SessionModel.Name, "actual", Request.Files[i].FileName),
        //Session = SessionModel,
        SessionID = SessionID
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you drop these lines, if you can workaround it (I can see the point though, in the `count`)...

```
context.Entry(ImageModel).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
SessionModel.PhotosCount = SessionModel.Images.Count;
context.Entry(SessionModel).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```

That's probably what's messing with it. I've seen similar problems more than once - and then I usually end up doing quite the opposite:

```
context.Entry(Parent).State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Everything you're doing there is to get the `Count` working.

I can understand the optimization reasons, but you do have that count in the collection inherently. I know this is faster if you don't want to load etc.

I'm not sure what to suggest - but I'm suspecting that to be the 'culprit'.

> Try w/o it, turn off and disregard count while testing. See what
>   happens. If that's it, then think about how to reorganize that a bit.